# Horizontal spaces to the left and right of theorems

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, theorems

How do I get horizontal spaces to the left and right of theorems? My initial idea was to do the following bad idea:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm

\newtheoremstyle{newplain}  % name of the style to be used
  {}                        % measure of space to leave above the theorem
  {}                        % measure of space to leave below the theorem
  {\addtolength{\leftskip}{2em}\addtolength{\rightskip}{2em}% this is probably bad!!!
   \itshape}                % commands on body of the theorem
  {}                        % measure of space to indent (empty = no indent, \parindent = para indent)
  {\bfseries}               % name of head font
  {.}                       % punctuation between head and body
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}  % space after theorem head
  {}                        % Manually specify head

\theoremstyle{newplain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{lemma}
The Lemma says
\begin{equation}
y=mx+c.
\end{equation}
\end{lemma}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{theorem}[Wigner-Eckart theorem]
The Matrix elements of a tensor operator can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
y=(\partial_x y)x+c.
\end{equation}
This equation does not does not have the correct formatting that was defined above.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: what doesn't this do that you want to be done?  it's not a great idea to reuse the name `\theoremstyle{plain}`, but to my surprise, there was no complaint, and the theorem *text* is indented on both sides as requested.  if it's the position of the equation number you want indented, that's a different kettle of fish.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I read the package amsthm and saw what it does such that I understood what I was doing by redefining the style. Of course, it is always better to give the new style a new name. My problem was that the position of the equations number was uaffected by my command. cmhughes' solution below corrects that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses the [`etoolbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/etoolbox) to wrap the  [`changepage`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/changepage)'s `adjustwidth` environment around your `theorem` environment.

The important parts are:

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{2cm}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{theorem}{\endadjustwidth}
```

You can obviously change the `2cm` as you see fit.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{changepage}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]  % numbered by the sections number

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{2cm}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{theorem}{\endadjustwidth}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{theorem}[Wigner-Eckart theorem]
    The Matrix elements of a tensor operator $T_{q}^{(1)}$ can be rewritten as
    \begin{equation}
        y=mx+c
    \end{equation}
\end{theorem}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how to define it for all theorem, lemma, corollary, etc. at once?

Comment: @strpeter as far as I know (I may be wrong), `amsthm` does not have that capability (`ntheorem` does). You'll just need to copy the `BeforeBeginEnvironment` and `AfterEndEnvironment` code for each in your preamble